# If I redesign my site and change the content, will AdSense continue?

Tags: google-adsense, content, redesign

I have a user content driven site, kind of like a blog or something. I had done it in good old PHP and MySQL. I display ads in it using Google AdSense.

But the website has gone stale now. So I am trying to do it using some node framework and Postgres as the backend.

I have migrated the content already, but I don't want to use the old content now, I want to completely redesign it, including the database.

I am concerned with my AdSense account. If I redesign my site, will the AdSense continue? Do they (AdSense) regularly check for old content?

Answer (score 2):

Google says that once you have been approved for AdSense you can place your AdSense codes on new sites without notifying Google as long as the new site complies with the Google Ads policies.

So yes, if you redesign, rebrand, or even create a new site altogether your AdSense ads would continue to show anywhere you place the AdSense code.

[Quote from Google](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/65063?hl=en):

> There's no need to open another account or notify us when you place
>   your ad code on a new site. Once your account is approved, whenever
>   you place your AdSense code on a new page, we'll automatically
>   associate that new site with your account.
>
> [Generate the AdSense code](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6002575) as you did for your original site, and add
>   it to whichever page you'd like — making sure, of course, that it
>   complies with our [program policies](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/48182). You don't need our team to
>   officially review your new site beforehand, but please use your best
>   judgment to make sure that your site content and ad implementation are
>   compliant. (Our [policy explanations](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1348688) might help.) We regularly review
>   sites displaying our ads, and we'll let you know if we find any
>   issues. Note that if you're using the authorized sites feature, you'll
>   need to add your new URL to your owned sites list, or you won't
>   receive any earnings for that URL.